# What are the known standards to map country names to super regions APAC, EMEA, and AMER?

Tags: geospatial, geocoding

I am looking for country-superregion mapping for the following super regions:

- APAC = Asia Pacific
- EMEA = Europe, Middle-East and Africa
- AMER = North, Central and South America

So far I have only seen a compiled list on [GitHub as a gist](https://gist.github.com/richjenks/15b75f1960bc3321e295). Would be great to have a standard list and wonder where I may be able to find such information.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is hard to find a standard compiled list of region wise countries. Here are some sources for different regions:

1. APAC: [UN ESCAP](https://data.unescap.org/dataviz/methodology/list-of-countries-in-the-asia-pacific-region-and-subregions.html)
2. EMEA : [ISTIZADA](https://istizada.com/list-of-emea-countries/)
3. AMER: [Map of all countries](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/270220990_Geographical_distribution_of_the_association_between_El_Nino_South_Oscillation_and_dengue_fever_in_the_Americas_A_continental_analysis_using_geographical_information_system-based_techniques)

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

FAO Geopolitical ontology should help https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geopolitical_ontology#FAO_ontology

Links are a bit rotten for now, but there is an archive at DataHub https://old.datahub.io/dataset/fao-geopolitical-ontology.

It was the most comprehensive ontology on country classification.

The alternative is the WorldBank Data project https://data.worldbank.org . Its data is available via API, and countries are also linked with geographic and economic territories.